# sequelize fulltext query using parameters

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, full-text-search

Hi I'm currently trying to query records from db and these are the conditions

- I receive 'order by', 'order (desc/asc)', 'limit', 'offset' from the frontend
- I also need to search the record using match...against. 'like' is too slow for searching.
- There's a mapped model with this query.

so I tried

```
    let order_by = req.query.orderby;
    let order = req.query.order;
    let page = req.query.pagenum;
    let perpage = req.query.parpage;
    let searchword = req.query.foodsearch;
    let offset = (parseInt(page) - 1) * parpage;

    let foods = await models.food.findAll({
        limit: parseInt(perpage),
        offset: offset,
        order: [
            [order_by, order]
        ],

    //  where: Sequelize.literal
    //  (
    //      `MATCH 
    //      (Name, Place, RestoNum, Ingredient, ChefName, Region...) 
    //      AGAINST
    //      ( ? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)`, 
    //      { replacements: [ searchword ] }
    //  )
    });
```

but the commented part seems wrong in this code.
I tried the raw query, but then I can't parameterize those order by, order, offset, limit variables.
I don't want to just add them like ${orderby} because it's risky.

Please let me know if you have any solution for this issue.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the `Sequelize.literal()` and `sequelizeInstance.query()` APIs.

1. [`.literal()` only take a string](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#static-method-literal).  If you want to use the object notation for your query, your commented code will work.  Except that there is no second argument.  You will need to concatenate-in or interpolate-in your search term into the `AGAINST` clause.  [Also, don't forget your quotes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html#:%7E:text=A%20phrase%20that%20is%20enclosed%20within%20double%20quote%20(%22)%20characters%20matches%20only%20rows%20that%20contain%20the%20phrase%20literally%2C%20as%20it%20was%20typed).  The output of the `literal()` is essentially a string.  Your MySQL FTS parameter will need the correct type of quotes around it, just as they would appear in your raw SQL query.
2. [`.query()` DOES take an options parameter.](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#instance-method-query)  Through this, you don't have to use string interpolation, [you can use named replacements or bound-parameters](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/raw-queries.html#replacements).  This will not only allow you to place in your `searchword` parameter, but whatever ORDER BY clause you want, as well.

I would go with Option 1.  That's what we are doing for our FTS, in MS SQL.

Comment: Thanks astangelo! that helped me a lot :)